# Get variable from alpine.js and add it to placeholder

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am trying to fetch a variable from an alpinejs format to put into placeholder of my input, the code is as follows:

```
<template x-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
    <input type="text" name="sort" placeholder="<want to put index here>" />
</template>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<template x-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
    <input type="text" name="sort" x-bind:placeholder="index" />
</template>
```

Comment: Omg, how did I not think of bind <face plant> ty!